# Javascript how can I find character "utf-16" at string

Tags: javascript, utf-16

Have a question. Sorry for my English.

I have a string. Customer enter SMS text at text-area. 
How can I find the existing character of `utf-16` at the string or not?

At php I check this code:

```
if (iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$_entry_text) != $_entry_text) {
  // exist utf-16
}
```

How can I at Javascript check? Try to find an answer the second day ((

Thanks.

Comment: I might be mistaken, or not understanding your question properly, but if they do enter it in a textarea, then the encoding should be set by the browser, and hence by your own page's encoding.

Comment: All characters in JavaScript are in the Unicode character set, using the UTF-16 character encoding, to be precise. It's not clear what you're asking. Is it for being in or not in some subset of Unicode, or also in or not in some other character set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a short string, one method would be to just look across the length of it and check if any of the char-codes sit outside of the single-byte 0-255 range

```
if (_entry_text.charCodeAt(i) > 255) ...
```

Comment: I should have elaborated, but UTF-8 uses both single and double bytes, UTF-16 would sit outside of the UTF-8 range, which is why it's > 255, and not  >127

Answer (score 3):

A string is a series of characters, each which have a character code. ASCII defines characters from 0 to 127, so if a character in the string has a code greater than that, then it is a Unicode character. This function checks for that. See [String#charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).

```
function hasUnicode (str) {
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str.charCodeAt(i) > 127) 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then use it like, hasUnicode("Test message");

Comment: That is incorrect. Extended ASCII (ASCII with codepage) uses characters above 127 and has nothing to do with unicode. Except if you know that your string is unicode, then this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need for a loop;

```
var ascii = /^[ -~]+$/;

ascii.test("Sefa"); // it is true no non-ascii characters
ascii.test("Sefa£"); // it is false there is non-ascii character
```